# CORS Error: Angular.JS, Node.JS and Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Having issues getting data back from a http post request to an API I've been building. Throws the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load (URL to API here). No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
> access.

Here's the Angular code on the client side:

```js
$http.post('MyAPIsURLHere', {
    date: $scope.information.PubDate
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
```

And here's the Node server side code for my API:

```js
app.post('/getThing', (req, res) => {
    const date = req.body.date;
    const query = Overquery
    const query2 = "alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/dd/yyyy'";

    oracleDB.execute(query2, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    oracleDB.execute(query, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        else {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

            res.json(result.rows);
        }
    });
});
```

First time building an API so any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're properly setting cors headers for the POST request, however, you're likely not properly responding to the OPTIONS request that comes before the post request in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in your project from a bash shell:

`npm install cors --save`

It will install this:
https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Then add this to your server when creating the app.

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

**Edit**: This will enable CORS for every domain wich is not recomended for security reasons. Check here for further CORS configuration: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors

Comment: Do not forget use cord before defining routes in your app.js

Answer (score 0):

In your node application, this sample of code should solve your issues:

```
// Allowing X-domain request
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control");

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.send(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: this one worked for me. can you add some explanation about this? and if it is safe for production ?